# Downloading a postgreSQL pg_dump file from a remote server using Python

Tags: python, postgresql, pg-dump

I'm struggling getting data from an older postgres database to an newer one.
I have already tried a few things without success. For more information, see [Useing ANSI driver to connect to a postgreSQL DB with python psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69978534/useing-ansi-driver-to-connect-to-a-postgresql-db-with-python-psycopg2)

The last idea is now to use pg_dump and pg_restore.

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

# destination handling has to be adjusted. 

def dump_table(host_name, database_name, user_name, database_password, table_name):

    command = 'pg_dump -h {0} -d {1} -U {2} -p 5432 -t public.{3} -Fc -f /tmp/table.dmp'.format(host_name, database_name, user_name, table_name)

    p = Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    
    return p.communicate('{}n'.format(database_password))
```

After some research, I came across the above approach. Unfortunately, I haven't really done anything with the shell yet. As I currently understand it, the postgresDB is addressed locally so that the table.dmp is stored there in the /tmp/ directory.
However, I do not have direct access to this directory in order to download files from it. Do I have a possibility to receive the file created here directly in Python in order to process it directly on the target server? Because the target server is the one I have access to.

Comment: You can use `pg_dump` locally to dump a remote database, just point it at the correct `host`. Also depends on the `port` being accessible. Though this means will be transferring all the data across a remote link, so it may be slow given database size.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver. Do you have a hint how to do that? I have a bit of a hard time with Shell. The standard port 5432 is not enough? I could change that.

Comment: At the command line: `pg_dump -h <remote_host> -d <some_db>  -U <some_user> -p 5432 -f some_db.out`. Again if the database is large and the network jump is large this may be slow. Also make sure the `pg_dump` you are using is from the newer version of Postgres.

Comment: Now I got you. Thanks. That's what I'm doing here. I get the corresponding values from a config file and pass them to the function. If I print the command to double check I receive: `pg_dump -h my_remote_url -d my_remote_db -U my_remote_db_User -p 5432 -t dbSchema.dbTable -Fc -f /tmp/table.dmp` But if I check my local path nothing is there. I'm able to build up a connection with psycopg2. I can therefore rule out the possibility of authorisations etc. The remote DB runs under PostgreSQL 9.4.20.

Comment: PS: If I run the script it runs without any returned issues in under a sec. But no data has been returned as I explained.

Comment: I've adjusted my command line above to use the schema correct. `'pg_dump -h {0} -d {1} -U {2} -p 5432 -t {3} -n {4} -Fc -f > ~/table.dump'`
I have tested whether a backup can be pulled remotely at all. I wanted to pull a dump via DBeaver. With compression I get a 146 mb file. According to the log, DBeaver seems to transfer a copy instead of pg_dump. I have now tried to import locally via pg_restore. Also from Python. Here, too, my script runs without error message in 0.5 seconds. However, nothing happens on the database. I set up the local database myself. It is running in the latest version.

Comment: Show the step by step procedure you are using in your question not as comments. Some questions 1) Does the remote database have any data in it? 2) Define 'import locally via pg_restore'? 3) Define what you did with DBeaver? In all cases add as update to your question, preferably as code samples not written descriptions.

Comment: I have recently solved my original problem. (See link in the initial description). 
The solution for this follow-up error has thus become obsolete. Nevertheless, many thanks for the support.